# 'Best' Diff Algorithm

Tags: vb.net, diff

I need to implement a Diff algorithm in VB.NET to find the changes between two different versions of a piece of text.  I've had a scout around the web and have found a couple of different algorithms.

Does anybody here know of a 'best' algorithm that I could implement?

Comment: [Here's another good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2817556/2388257) suitable to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I've used the c# version on codeproject and its really good for what I wanted...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx

You can probably get this translated into VB.net via an [online converter](http://labs.developerfusion.co.uk/convert/csharp-to-vb.aspx) if you can't do it yourself...

Comment: This should be a comment, how got it accepted? There's no even mention what diff algorithm is used in the linked project.

Answer (score 7):

I like [An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and Its Variations](http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf) by Eugene Myers. I believe it's the algorithm that was used in GNU diff. For a good background see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff).

This is quite theoretical and you might wish to find source code, but I'm not aware of any in VB.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for sure if it's the best diff algorithms but you might want to check out those links that talks about SOCT4 and SOCT6

http://dev.libresource.org/home/doc/so6-user-manual/concepts

and also:
http://www.loria.fr/~molli/pmwiki/uploads/Main/so6group03.pdf
http://www.loria.fr/~molli/pmwiki/uploads/Main/diffalgo.pdf