# How to detect duplicate text with some fuzzyness

Tags: text, diff, duplicates, duplicate-data, duplication

Some thing ago, I write [small script](http://svn.rot13.org/index.cgi/refeed/view/trunk/deduper/reblog-dupe.pl) using [Text::DeDupe](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-DeDuper/) to remove duplicates of blog posts before I have to lay my eyes on them.

After reading [Syntactic Clustering of the Web](http://www.ra.ethz.ch/CDstore/www6/Technical/Paper205/Paper205.html) paper on which implementation is based, I would love to have ability to find overlapping documents (e.g. snippets of blogs as opposed to full text, maybe also quotes).

Do you know of any other implementation in C, C++ or perl which I can try out before writing my own?

Comment: I think you'd have to use classic line-based differencing algorithms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236031/how-to-realize-a-diff-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145607/text-difference-algorithm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144/best-diff-algorithm

Comment: This might be too simplistic approach to task at hand since I would like to remove near-duplicates like someone quoting most of post and adding something like "me too" which is just spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpotSigs seems to fit my bill just right, here are some references:

- http://dbpubs.stanford.edu/pub/2008-10
- http://infoblog.stanford.edu/2008/08/spotsigs-are-stopwords-finally-good-for.html
- http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/860/

The soruce code for this module is hosted on GitHub:

http://github.com/jzawodn/perl-text-spotsig

Comment: That Jeremy Z. github link isn't the link to the source. If you look at that repo it is empty. The source to SpotSigs can be found here: http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mtb/

Comment: The page mentioned by Nate has moved, this is the new URL: http://adrem.ua.ac.be/~tmartin/